# Unable to save text to database with 'body' => htmlentities($_POST['body']) on server, but on localhost it works

Tags: php, mysql, html-entities

I have an array called $data and I am sending this data to my db insert method.

This works nice when used with:

```
'body' => $_POST['body']
```

However, when I try:

```
'body' => htmlentities($_POST['body'])
```

Only a first 3 words are saved but when it comes to character **ě** it stops there and other parts of the text is not saved.

in my db body is stored in body column which is a standard text type, utf_8_general_ci.

It has nothing to do with db settings I guess, because all tables is set to uf8_general_ci as well as the table itself (the same as on my localhost).

The funniest part is that on my localhost machine running wamp it wokrs with al these weird characters and the text is saved correctly when sing htmlentities.

Only on the server it didn't work. Btw. it's justhost if it helps.

Do you know how to run it the same way as on my localhost or any other function that can be used except htmlentities ?

I need htmlentities because I have html code like google maps and it needs to be saved. Without htmlentities it is saved incorrectly.

Comment: HI, Can you please state that which field type you keep in Database and add some sample HTML data here -:)

Comment: ok, I will add that in a minute

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is serious problem. I really need to solve this problem. It's probably something with server settings or maybe php.ini settings. Any idea?

Comment: Hmm, yes that's probably it. I will try it.

Comment: @ZZ-bb Thanks a lot man, this seems to be working `'body' => htmlentities($_POST['body'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')` ;) . Please, add it as an answer so I can chose yours as the correct one.

Comment: Did it, thanks. (Removed my comment above.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and set the [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) encoding to match your form data encoding.

Note the dividing PHP version 5.4.0: default encoding for htmlentities can be UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1. Does your local machine have the same PHP version as server?

Note to all local machine users (MAMP, WAMP, LAMP, whatever): always check your PHP/MySQL versions if they match the server version. There is almost always some common function that doesn't work as expected when the testing environment isn't identical to production environment (been there, done that – once or twice...).

Answer (score 1):

Try using mysql_real_escape_string or mysqli_real_escape_string or prepared statements when inserting into a DB.

Comment: It porduces stuff like \n\n\n\n\n\n\n. Not worrking at all ;(

Comment: Yes, because it escapes the things that need to be escaped. That's how real_escape works! So don't downvote because you did not know that. But did it now save everything (in spite of \n\n)?

Comment: But when I try to show that on my page it outputs n/n/n/ as well and that produces errors. I don't want to save /n/n/n in my db at first place. Why? I need to export that to excel and it looks horrible. The downvote is not because it doesn't work but because because your answer was a comment, not an answer. In your own words: "Maybe that will help".

Comment: Wow, really, that why the downvote. I removed it, so you can remove the downvote. Just use prepared statements to insert it. Or real_escape and than strip the \n when retrieving the data. That's all.

Answer (score -1):

You can use set utf8 to mysql before insertion. It can insert special character in the database. FYI http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php

Comment: why -1 here,explain please